# Extra margin in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, margin

I'm trying to make a canvas that fits perfectly in a square browser. The problem is keep getting this extra margin at the top and left of the screen  and I'm unable to get rid of it. Any idea how I can fix this?

[image: red arrows]

**Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<style type="text/css">

#gameCanvas {
    background-color: blue;
}

</style>

<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");  
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerWidth;
</script>
<script src="cocos2d.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Katherine Huang said, browsers have default stylesheets that include margins, padding...

You can set this:

```
html, body{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#gameCanvas{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Now you will have to set specific margins and paddings on every new element inside the body, becouse by default they will have 0.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers have default stylesheets that include margins, padding, and more. Try this:

```
body {
    padding: 0;
}
```

In general, CSS resets come in handy when overriding default styles.

Comment: How about `* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`? `*` is the universal selector, so this will set the padding and margins to 0 for all elements.